# encoding/xml Unmarshal on dynamically structure elements

Tags: xml, go

I'm **working with epubs using Golang**, I have to fetch the cover image from cover.xhtml file (or whatever file it is mentioned in .opf file).

**My problem is with dynamic structure of elements in the Cover.xhtml files.**

Each epubs has different structure on the Cover.xhtml file. For example,

```
<body>
    <figure id="cover-image">
        <img src="covers/9781449328030_lrg.jpg" alt="First Edition" />
    </figure>
</body>
```

Another epub cover.xhtml file

```
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@54869@54869-h@images@cover.jpg" alt="Cover" />
    </div>
</body>
```

I need to **fetch the img tag's src attribute from this file**. But I couldn't do it.

Here is the part of my Code that deals with unmarshalling the cover.xhtml file

```
type CPSRCS struct {
    Src string `xml:"src,attr"`
}

type CPIMGS struct {
    Image CPSRCS `xml:"img"`
}

XMLContent, err = ioutil.ReadFile("./uploads/moby-dick/OPS/cover.xhtml")
CheckError(err)

coverFile := CPIMGS{}
err = xml.Unmarshal(XMLContent, &coverFile)
CheckError(err)
fmt.Println(coverFile)
```

The output is:

```
{{}}
```

The output I'm expecting is:

```
{{covers/9781449328030_lrg.jpg}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two problems: First: Why do you expect that unmarshaling `body > figure > img` into a flat CPRS should work at all? Where should body and figure go? That's not how xml unmarshalling works. Second: You'll need some programming to distinguish the different formats and unmarshal them differently.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to golang.. Is there a way to parse the image link through string handling?

Comment: Why would you fiddle with strings if you can unmarshal (albeit not into your too simple structure)?

Comment: @Volker that is how XML unmarshalling works. body and figure don't have to go anywhere. Elements in the XML that don't appear in the struct are simply dropped, same as with JSON.

Comment: @mk there is a working solution in an answer, but just thought I'd toss out another option, using XPath. There is no XPath support in stdlib but there are several third-party libraries that implement it. You can use it to select an element from an XML document dynamically without unmarshaling.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for notifying about XPath. I used that in Python. I'll look for  Go libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pull out the `img` element from the read in file and then unmarshal the src attribute from the element. This is making the assumption that you will only ever need to grab the first `img` element from the file.

```
XMLContent, err = ioutil.ReadFile("./uploads/moby-dick/OPS/cover.xhtml")
CheckError(err)

//Parse the XMLContent to grab just the img element
strContent := string(XMLContent)
imgLoc := strings.Index(strContent, "<img")
prefixRem := strContent[imgLoc:]
endImgLoc := strings.Index(prefixRem, "/>")
//Move over by 2 to recover the '/>'
trimmed := prefixRem[:endImgLoc+2]

var coverFile CPSRCS
err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(trimmed), &coverFile)
CheckError(err)
fmt.Println(coverFile)
```

This will produce the result of {covers/9781449328030_lrg.jpg} for the first input file and {@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@54869@54869-h@images@cover.jpg} for the second input file you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially for that you took my code and gave me an example :) Yes there will be only one img tag in the cover.xhtml file.